# getFillForegroundColor, Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

So i'm using Apache POI library for reading an Excel file (.xlsx), and what i'm trying to do is simple:
I want to iterate through all the cells but read the text of only red\yellow\green\blue cells, and skip all the others.

Assume this:

- The file loaded is not empty and contains colorated cells,
- I imported all the needed libraries.

Following the guide (http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator), i ended up coding this:

```
...
...            
// why 15? 1400? no idea.. the guide doesn't explain... also isn't it dangerous??
         int rowStart = Math.min(15, sheet.getFirstRowNum());
         int rowEnd = Math.max(1400, sheet.getLastRowNum());

            // iterate through ROWS: 
            for (int rowNum = rowStart; rowNum < rowEnd; rowNum++) {

                // returns 'rowNum' row of current sheet:
                Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum); 
                if(r == null) {
                           System.out.println("empty row skipped");
                           continue;
                           }


                // iterate through CELLS: 
                for (Cell cell : r) {

                    if(cell == null) {
                        System.out.println("empty cell");
                        continue;
                        }

                        XSSFColor colore = (XSSFColor) cell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColorColor();

                        if (colore == null) {
                                System.out.println("something wrong?");
                                continue;
                            }
                            // checking colors like this:
                        if(colore.getARGBHex().substring(2, 5).equals("FFFF")){
                                // working on cell
                                continue;
                            }

                        if(colore.getARGBHex().substring(4, 5).equals("FF")){
                                // working on cell
                                continue;
                            }

                        if(colore.getARGBHex().substring(6, 7).equals("FF")){
                                // working on cell
                                continue;
                            }

                        if(colore.getARGBHex().substring(2, 3).equals("FF")){
                                // working on cell
                                continue;
                            }

                        }
```

When i execute the code, it ends up printing "Something wrong?" thousand times, as if colore is alwais null in all the cells.
So questions are:

1. why it alwais find colore null? (i also tried
   .getFillBackgroundColorColor())
2. is there a smarter way for checking the colors rather than using those 
   horrible if-statements?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, do you have more than 15 rows in your Excel? Those numbers in the example are just arbitrary. You would have done better to follow the example that follows that one. It's an example of how to handle empty cells, which you don't need anyway.

Comment: @RealSkeptic already tried with other numbers (1, 150..), but it still doesn't work. Anyway shouldn't "getFirstRowNum()"  alwais give 0? i image rows numbered from 0 to n. I don't get the point of using min\max functions to give a bound..

Comment: There is no point, except as a demonstration that will give you some empty cells. As I said, that example is only for explaining how to handle empty cells. If you have any cells there they are probably being swept out of the console before you can see them. Why aren't you using the iterators like in the examples before and after that one?

Comment: @RealSkeptic ok then, but anyway the main problem is that every cell i check with getFillForeGroundColorColor alwais returns null, when actually the cell exists and, sometimes, is even colorated. Even if it's blank, shouldn't it return something?